# System Verilog Coverpoint Bin for everything else that is counted towards coverage calculations

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

Setting a bin to default grabs everything else in the coverpoint, but the default bin is ignored in coverage calcuations. Is there anything similar to default that I can use for syntax that will generate a bin to cover "everything else" in a coverpoint but code in coverage calculations? Alternatively is there way I can tag the default bin so that it will be counted in code coverage calculations?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a bin for "everything else" to be counted towards coverage is the same thing as not specifying any bins for your coverpoint.

If you are trying to get a particular set of bin groupings, you might be better off specifying two coverpoints of the same expression. The first coverpoint has the bins you specifically wanted to pick out, and the second coverpoint ignores the bins from the first set. There might be better ways of doing this, but that would depend on the specific situation.